# What is the relationship between psychological entitlement and locus of control or other personal characteristics?

Tags: social-psychology, personality, study-cognitive-sciences

I'm studying psychology and I have the assignment to write an experimental study I'm still collecting the scientific information on the topic so I would really appreciate some help. 
I'm interested to know:

- What is the relationship between psychological entitlement and locus of control?
- What scientific studies have been conducted on the relation between psychological entitlement and locus of control or some other personal characteristic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Psychological entitlement (the belief that one should get preferential treatment) is positively related to an external locus of control (the belief that personal outcomes are due to chance or powerful others).**

For example, Anderson et al. (2013), report that the Personal Entitlement Scale (Campbell et al., 2004) is correlated with r=.43 to more external answers on the Locus of Control Scale by Rotter (1954). Similarly, for entitlement beliefs in the academic realm, Kopp et al. report positive correlations of entitlement beliefs with the Locus of Control - Chance and Locus of Control - Powerful Others subscales of the Levenson (1973) [scale](http://www.hannalevenson.com/ipcscales.pdf).

The last part of the question (what are other correlates of entitlement?) is very broad. Campbell et al.'s (2004) scale is frequently [cited](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=490866267960059457) in research on entitlement, this should be a good starting point into this research field.

**References**

Anderson, D., Halberstadt, J., & Aitken, R. (2013). Entitlement Attitudes Predict Students’ Poor Performance in Challenging Academic Conditions. International Journal of Higher Education, 2. doi:10.5430/ijhe.v2n2p151

Campbell, W. K., Bonacci, A. M., Shelton, J., Exline, J. J., & Bushman, B. J. (2004). Psychological Entitlement: Interpersonal Consequences and Validation of a Self-Report Measure. Journal of Personality Assessment, 83, 29–45. doi:10.1207/s15327752jpa8301_04

Kopp, J. P., Zinn, T. E., Finney, S. J., & Jurich, D. P. (2011). The Development and Evaluation of the Academic Entitlement Questionnaire. Measurement and Evaluation in Counseling and Development, 44, 105–129. doi:10.1177/0748175611400292

Levenson, H. (1973). Multidimensional locus of control in psychiatric patients. Journal of Consulting and Clinical Psychology, 41, 397–404

Rotter, J. B. (1954). Social learning and clinical psychology. New York, NY: Prentice Hall. doi:10.1037/10788-000

Comment: Awesome answer, I would have vote-up it as well, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to do so. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting!

on a very basic level, you'd want to start in exploring reward mechanisms- according to the stimuli, there would be a planned reaction associated to the stimuli conditioned over time. i don't see locus of control as a perrsonal characteristic inherent to the inner-workings of one's thought on selfhood, but rather as a trained pattern which becomes structurally hard-wired. a google scholar search on this looks at locus of control and attribution in relation to access to academia here: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11218-012-9184-4#page-1

the article seems to look at an ok sample-size - all from 1 u.s. southern university :/

i wonder if by entitlement you are referring to class??

Comment: Hi Nanja, Thank you for your reply. Actually I've get a lot of work done on my assignment last night. By entitlement I'm referring exactly to the psychological understanding of entitlement - Psychological entitlement refers to a stable, pervasive tendency to see oneself as more deserving than others (Campbell, Bonacci, Shelton, Exline, & Bushman, 2004). If you are anyhow interested in the subject I CAn send you the articles I've got on it.